# Select a dictionary from list of dictionaries based on count

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am pretty new to C# Lambda expressions. Is there any possibility to get a dictionary from a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` based on its count of rows? I want the one with max count.

below is a screenshot of my code with a brief description:

[image]

Comment: `var i = columnDescription.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Count == 2);` I would use `Single` here unless you do not care which one is returned if there is more than 1 match.

Comment: What needs to happen if the count is same, do you want to overwrite or append the values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> BigOne = CoulmnsDescription.OrderByDescending(dic => dic.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer satisfied my requirement.